# ConverterNotFoundException when running native query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my application, I have the following function in a `@Repository` class:

```
@Query(value="SELECT roster_date FROM timetable", nativeQuery=true)
List<LocalDate> getAllDates();
```

When I execute the above query, I ran into the following `ConverterNotFoundException`:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query java.util.List<java.time.LocalDate>] 
for value '[2019-04-19 00:00:00.0, 2019-04-21 00:00:00.0]'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.sql.Timestamp] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query java.time.LocalDate]
```

I tried to register a custom converter as following but it doesn't work as well.

```
@Component
public class SqlTimestampToLocalDateConverter implements Converter<Timestamp, LocalDate> {
    @Override
    public LocalDate convert(Timestamp source) {
        return source.toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

If I call `findById` to get a SINGLE record using my `@Entity` class which contains a `LocalDate` property for the `roster_date` column then it's working fine.

I'd be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Works for me with Spring Boot 2.1.4 - sample [here](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/55741445). Can you add the Spring Boot version number to the question?

Comment: @manish: Thanks for giving it a try. I'm also using 2.1.4. Can you try with `nativeQuery=true` and make sure your seed data contains more than 1 date? In my database, I do have the values that are shown in the exception with that exact format `2019-04-19 00:00:00.0`.

Comment: Do you really need a native query? You can download my sample project and try out a few things.

Comment: @manish: I'm using a very simple query as an example to ask the question. In my actual use case, it's a complex query which returns multiple dates in the format `2019-04-19 00:00:00.0`. I can't use JPQL :(.

Comment: If you are facing a problem specifically with native queries, you may want to raise an issue in the Spring JIRA. It is quite possible that there is a bug in Spring Data that fails a native query but not a JPA query.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an entity class, you can use this instead, I guess your entity class is named Time:

```
@Query("select t.rosterDate from Time t")
```

If you already have entity classes use could use JPQL.